# How do I loop through two columns (after finding the column header) and calculate the difference?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write VBA code to loop through two seperate columns given the column name "Market Segment" and then use two offsets the first one being Offset.(0,2) and then loop down 13 rows calculating the difference from a column with an offset.(0,6).

I am trying to make this as dynamic as possible so I want to refrain using rang (A2:A15).

[image: example of data table]

I was trying to loop through as I feel this will be the most efficient way but as I am new to VBA if there is a more efficient way I am definitely open to that.

Here is the code I have written, I just dont know how to utilize this in a loop

```
Sub Difference() 
    Dim Sh As Worksheet 
    Dim Portfolio As Range 
    Dim MarketSeg As Range 

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        With Sh.UsedRange 
            Set MarketSeg = .Cells.Find(What:="Market Segment") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't appear that you are *'trying to write VBA code'* at all. More like you are trying to get someone else to write code for you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Here is the code I have written, I just dont know how to utilize this in a loop...

Comment: Please can you add that to your question - as you can see it's not readable in a comment?

Comment: Once you find the `Market Segment` what are you supposed to do? You have no mention of finding the data in the other parts of your image or why you have the 2 cell offsets. There isn't enough information here for us to even understand what exactly you are trying to do. Your code example looks like the beginning of something that never did anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for Market Segment, why not look for the row that has "Total" on column A, the code below will do that and prompt the user of any difference:

```
Sub Difference()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Total As Range

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set Total = Sh.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Total", LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'look for "Total" on Column A in each Sheet
            DifferenceVal = Val(Total.Offset(0, 2)) - Val(Total.Offset(0, 6))
            'calculate difference
            MsgBox "Difference is " & DifferenceVal 'prompt user
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to find "Market Segment" and then offset by where you find the "Total" row, the following will do that:

```
Sub Difference()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Total As Range
    Dim Market As Range
    Dim FirstVal As String
    Dim SecondVal As String
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set Total = Sh.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Total", LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'look for "Total" on Column A in each Sheet to find the offset value
            Set Market = Sh.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Market Segment", LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'look for "Market Segment" on Column A in each Sheet
            FirstVal = Market.Offset(Total.Row - 2, 2) 'offset by Total - 2 for headers
            SecondVal = Market.Offset(Total.Row - 2, 6)
            DifferenceVal = Val(FirstVal) - Val(SecondVal)
            'calculate difference
            MsgBox "Difference is " & DifferenceVal 'prompt user
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Xabier this was helpful. The reason I wasnt going to look at the total is because I was going to evaluate each individual difference for each sector in another piece of code. I think I should be able to utilize the code you wrote and then add to it to output the difference into another column. I really appreciate your help.